# Symmetries and morphisms of a circle

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have a question that I don't know how to approach. Here is the question:

Consider the group of symmetries of a circle denoted by $D_\infty$. Let $SD_\infty$ denote the subgroup of $D_\infty$ consisting of only rotations.

Let $\phi: D_\infty \rightarrow \{1,-1\}$ be defined by $\phi(x)=$ $1$, if x is a rotation and $-1$ if x is a reflection.

How can I prove that $D_\infty$ is not isomorphic to $SD_\infty$ x $\{-1,1\}$?

I should show that they do not share a certain group-theoretic property, but the problem is, I don't even know what $SD_\infty$ x $\{-1,1\}$ means.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if $G$ and $G'$ are two groups, then $G \times G'$ is their Cartesian product, with multiplication given by $(g_1, g'_1) \cdot (g_2, g'_2) = (g_1 g_2, g'_1 g'_2)$, where the multiplication in the first factor is done in the group $G$ and the multiplication in the second factor is done in the group $G'$.

Here are some hints for your problem:

(1) Show that $SD_{\infty} \times \{ 1 \}$ is an abelian group.  (More generally, $G \times G'$ is abelian if $G$ and $G'$ are.)

(2) Show that $D_{\infty}$ is not abelian by showing that rotations and reflections do not commute in general.

Comment: Ok thanks. Regarding hint (2), since $D_\infty$ is abelian, does it not follow that all of its subgroups are normal?

Comment: And does it not follow that all subgroups of index 2 are normal?

Comment: The group $D_{\infty}$ is not abelian (rotations and reflections do not commute with each other), but your second point is spot on.  I've edited my answer because my initial suggestion was wrong.  Sorry for the confusion.